# Submit and Save PDF Files and JPG/PNG Files in same form

Tags: php, cakephp, file-upload

I have a form where users should be able to upload images in one input, and PDFs in another. They can only upload one or the other. My problem is that since I added the PDF Field, users can no longer upload images. The database is still retrieving the image name, but the image is not being uploaded to the server.

My form in a view:

```
 <?= $this->Form->create($work, ['class'=> 'worksform', 'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']) ?>

<?= $this->Html->image('upload.png', ['class' => 'uploadform center']); ?>

<div class="worksformname"><?= $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.first_name')?> <?= $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.last_name');?></div>

<fieldset>
        <div class= "worksformtitle"><?= $this->Form->control('Title');?></div>

        <div class= "worksformcourse"><?= $this->Form->control('course_id', ['options' => $courses]);?></div>

        <div class= "worksformunit"><?= $this->Form->control('unit_id', ['options' => $units]); ?></div>

        <div class= "worksformdesc" data-container="body"><?= $this->Form->control('description');?></div>

        <p class="worksformtext">I want to upload a... </p>

        <li class="buttonworks">
        <button type="button" class="videoworks"id="videob"> Video Project </button>
        <button type="button" class="audioworks" id="audiob">  Audio Project</button>
        <button type="button" class="pdfworks" id="pdfb"> PDF File </button>
        <button type="button" class="imageworks" id="imageb"> Image File </button> </li>

        <div class="worksformvideo d-none" id="videof" data-container="body"><?= $this->Form->control('video_url')?> </div>

        <div class="worksformvideo d-none" id="audiof" data-container="body" ><?= $this->Form->control('sound_url');?> </div>

        <div class="worksformvideo d-none"id="pdff"><?= $this->Form->control('pdf', ['type'=> 'file'])?> </div>

        <div class="worksformvideo d-none"id="imagef"><?= $this->Form->control('image', ['type'=> 'file'])?> </div>
</fieldset>
<div class="buttonbox">
   <?=$this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
    </div>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public function add()
{
    $work = $this->Works->newEntity();

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $work = $this->Works->patchEntity($work, $this->request->getData());
        $work->user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');

        $file =$this->request->data['image'];
        $name =$this->request->data['image']['name'];

        $work->image_url = $name;

        $file =$this->request->data['pdf'];
        $name1 =$this->request->data['pdf']['name'];

        $work->pdf_url = $name1;

        if ($this->Works->save($work)) {
            move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . 'files/' . $name);
            $this->Flash->success(__('The work has been saved.'));

            move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . 'files/' . $name1);
           $this->Flash->success(__('The work has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The work could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
    $users = $this->Works->Users->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $units = $this->Works->Units->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $courses = $this->Works->Courses->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('work', 'users', 'units', 'courses'));


}
```

Output in the view:

```
   <div class="worksviewcontainer">

<p class="worksunitcourseview"> <?= $work->course->name?> / <?= $work->unit->name?></p>

<?php if(isset($work->sound_url) && !empty($work->sound_url)): ?>   
<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/<?= h($work->sound_url)?>&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true"></iframe>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if(isset($work->video_url) && !empty($work->video_url)): ?>
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?= h($work->video_url)?>" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if(isset($work->pdf_url) && !empty($work->pdf_url)): ?>
<object  class="pdfviewer" data="<?= '/~i7437085/project/files/'.$work->pdf_url ?>" type="application/pdf" width="600" height="500">
    <embed src="<?= '/~i7437085/project/files/'.$work->pdf_url ?>" width="600px" height="500px" />
        <p>This browser does not support PDFs. Please download the PDF to view it: 
        <a href="<?= '/~i7437085/project/files/'.$work->pdf_url ?>">Download PDF</a>.</p> 
    </embed>
    </object>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if(isset($work->image_url) && !empty($work->image_url)): ?>
<img class="pc" src="<?= '/~i7437085/project/files/'.$work->image_url ?>">
<?php endif; ?>

<p class="workstitleview"> <?= h($work->Title)?> </p>

<p class="worksnameview"> Published by <?= $work->user->first_name?> <?=$work->user->last_name?> (<?= $work->course->name?>) on <?= h($work->created) ?></p>

<p class="descheading">Description</p>         

<p class="worksdescview"><?= h($work->description); ?></p>

<div class="commentsheadingcontainer">
<p class="commentsheading">Comments Section</p>
 </div> 

<div class="workcomments">
<?= $this->Form->create($workComment, ['url' => ['controller' => 'WorkComments', 'action' => 'add']]) ?>
    <fieldset>
       <div class="row">
        <div class="commentsname"><?= $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.first_name')?> <?= $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.last_name');?></div>
        </div> 
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-11 nopadding">
            <div class="comments-field"><?= $this->Form->control('comment',['placeholder'=>'Type Comment', 'label'=> false ]);?></div>
            <?= $this->Form->hidden('work_id', ['value' => $work->id]);?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1">
                <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
                <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
        </div>
        </div>
        </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: `$file =$this->request->data['pdf'];`  If no pdf is loaded, that will be empty, wiping out whatever may have been put there by the image data.

Comment: Is there a work around for this?

Comment: Well, you say that the user is only allowed to upload one or the other, so one option would be to conditionally only run the related code when that file type is uploaded.  If an image is uploaded, run the image code. If a pdf is uploaded, run the pdf code.  Alternatively, you could probably do what you're doing with `$name` and `$name1` by having `$file` and `$file1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the problem is in:

```
    $file =$this->request->data['image'];
    $name =$this->request->data['image']['name'];

    $work->image_url = $name;

    $file =$this->request->data['pdf'];
    $name1 =$this->request->data['pdf']['name'];

    $work->pdf_url = $name1;
```

so `$file` is always equal to pdf data. You need to change it to something like:

```
if ($this->request->data['image']) {
    $file =$this->request->data['image'];
    $name =$this->request->data['image']['name'];

    $work->image_url = $name;
} else ($this->request->data['pdf']) {
    $file =$this->request->data['pdf'];
    $name1 =$this->request->data['pdf']['name'];

    $work->pdf_url = $name1;
}
```